Understanding GAN Proof
I was reading the original GAN paper, and in the proof of Proposition 2, it is states that $U(p_g, D)$ is convex in $p_g$. I'm not sure how this is implied to be convex. This comment said that it was to do with the assumption that $D$ can achieve its optimum, but I'm not sure how this implies convexity. Any help is appreciated.
